# Select a valid choice. ["objects"] is not one of the available choices. in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-2.2, multiplechoicefield

I'm going to create a form where the user can select any number of objects from the options.`(MultipleChoiceField)`

Here are my files:

```
DAY_CHOICES = (
('saturday', 'شنبه'),
('sunday', 'یکشنبه'),
('monday', 'دوشنبه'),
('tuesday', 'سه شنبه'),
('wednesday', 'چهارشنبه'),
('thursday', 'پنج شنبه'),
('friday', 'جمعه'),)

# Models.py
class CorporationRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, )
    explain = models.CharField(max_length=500, )
    assistance = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=ASSISTANCE_CHOICES)
    days =   # MultipleChoiceField
    created_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)

# Forms.py
class ObjectsForm(ModelForm):
    objects = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                     choices=OBJECT_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectModel
        fields = '__all__'
# Views.py 
def add_corporation(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ObjectsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_corporation = form.save(commit=False)
            new_corporation.days = ','.join(form.cleaned_data['days'])
            new_corporation.save()
            return redirect('administrator:view_admin_user_corporation')
    else:
        form = ObjectsForm()
    template = 'corporation.html'
    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

When I click on the submit button (for example select object 1 and 2), I get this error:

```
Select a valid choice. ['1', '2'] is not one of the available choices.-
```

**Hint:** each user send request to us that contain explanation and days that he can do something. So, Each user can select any day that he want.

Comment: Your model uses `DAY_CHOICES` and your form uses `OBJECT_CHOICES`

Comment: A `MultipleChoiceField` doesn't make much sense for a `CharField` especially one that has choices

Comment: I corrected `Day_CHOICES` , but the error still there. @IainShelvington

Comment: Like I said, you've used a `MultipleChoiceField` and tried to pass that value to a `CharField` with choices, it just won't work. Why is the form field a multiple select?

Comment: I couldn't understand this sentence: A `MultipleChoiceField` doesn't make much sense for a `CharField` especially one that has choices. @IainShelvington

Comment: I need Multiple choice. But i don't know how to implement that. @IainShelvington

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197540/discussion-between-whale-52hz-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must leave `CorporationRequest.days` as a `CharField` then you can save the day choices as a comma separated string in the field

```
class CorporationRequest(models.Model):
    days = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

You have to clean the data coming from the multiple choice field so that it can be saved in the field

```
class CorporationRequestForm(ModelForm):
    days = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                 choices=DAY_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = CorporationRequest
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_days(self):
        return ','.join(self.cleaned_data['days'])
```

This will mean that `CorporationRequest.days` is now a string and not a list of days. You could add a method to the `CorporationRequest` model to return the list of days

```
def get_days(self):
    return self.days.split(',')
```

Comment: And how can I  use these to method in `views.py`?@iain-shelvington

Comment: The same as you were before, you were using a model form before right?

Comment: I assumed "Object" was just a replacement for "CorporationRequest"

Comment: I use model form in sample way ! No such as this.  @iain-shelvington

Comment: You did have a form that you were using to get the error in the title

Comment: Replace that form or just the field and clean method on that form

Comment: I can't understand! Can you write this ? @iain-shelvington

Comment: Write what? You’ve not shared the view or form that you are actually using so I can make changes to them

Comment: Ahaaa I got this. Always When I need something in `ModelForm` I write that in my `view`. For example in this case I add this line of code to my view: `new_corporation = form.save(commit=False)
            new_corporation.days = ','.join(form.cleaned_data['days'])`@iain-shelvington

Comment: All things working. But if I want to recieve `days` form models as `set` that each day has that `label` such as `DAY_CHOICES` ? @iain-shelvington

Comment: `set(self.days.split(','))`

Comment: But in this way, I lost the `labels`. For example   I can n't set to `saturday` this lable: `('saturday', 'شنبه')` @iain-shelvington